# Nested foreach loops binding issue in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I am getting a double nested array from the server but am having trouble displaying the results using knockout.

Here is the result I am getting from the server.

[image]

The leves of the arrays is,

```
- Columns
  - reporttypes
     - reports
       - AvailableInCognos
     - reports
        - AvailableInCognos
  - reporttypes
     - reports
       - AvailableInCognos
- Columns
   - reporttypes
- ....
```

This is the code js code.

```
function mainViewModel() {
    self = this;

    self.reports = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.reporttypes = ko.observableArray(self.reports());
    self.columns = ko.observableArray(self.reporttypes());

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (result) {
            self.columns.push(result);
        }
    });
}

return mainViewModel;
```

Html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: columns">
    <div class="landing-group" data-bind="foreach: reporttypes">
        <div class="standard-container" data-bind="foreach: reports">
            <h2 class="txt-upper" data-bind="text: AvailableInCognos"></h2> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives me this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return reporttypes }" Message: reporttypes is not defined

Comment: Does your data look like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/10/

Comment: @Matt.k yes, that is correct, but my data is just returning an array of arrays of arrays. There is no specific name, for the collections.

Comment: Can you hard-coded exact data that you get in JSffidle like I did?

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: Please provide the new jsfiddle's link after updating

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/12/

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot that you've put with the output of data doesn't really correlate to the fiddle you've provided. `data` is supposed to be an array and yet in your fiddle it's an object. You call data structures `Array` in your nested code, and yet they are objects (and should be arrays - according to that screenshot). Not sure why would you want to create 3 separate arrays, you could just use simplier code with one, such as:

```js
var data = [
  [
    [{
      AvailableInCognos: true
    }]
  ],
  [
    [{
      AvailableInCognos: false
    }]
  ]
]
console.log(data);

function vm() {
  self = this;

  self.columns = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.columns(data);
  return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: columns">
  <div class="landing-group" data-bind="foreach: { data: $data, as: 'reportType' }">
    <div class="standard-container" data-bind="foreach: { data: $data, as: 'report' }">
      <h2 class="txt-upper" data-bind="text: AvailableInCognos ? 'Available' : 'Not available'"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```